# Authorization using action filter and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I'm trying to make my own authorization filter by implementing `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` so it has dependencies to repositories and user manager (they are using EF). I tried to resolve it by using `Inject` attribute but it injects a disposed instance (exactly same problem asked here : [MVC3 Action Filter Using Database (EF 4.1 DBContext, Ninject)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758611/mvc3-action-filter-using-database-ef-4-1-dbcontext-ninject))

So I tried to get my dependencies using `bootstrapper`:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        UserManager = (UserManager<User>)Startups.NinjectConfig.bootstrapper.Kernel.GetService(typeof(UserManager<User>));
        // other repositories are same as user manager.

        // check user access

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
```

It works fine and I have my repository instances but it throws this exception when it gets two (or more) requests at same time:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed.

Ninject bindings are in request scope.

Why this happens and what is best way to solve this?